# GNU make: several targets in one pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, groff, troff

With explicit targets I can combine several rules like

```
foo.o bar.o: $(SOURCES)
    cc $< -o $@
```

This is equivalent of

```
foo.o: $(SOURCES)
    cc $< -o $@
bar.o: $(SOURCES)
    cc $< -o $@
```

But I want to use pattern rules.

I have several troff documents (`man`, `README`) and I want to generate `.html` and `.ascii` files.

Naive approach is

```
GROFF := groff
DOCS := man README

DOC_FILES = $(foreach doc,$(DOCS),$(doc).html $(doc).ascii)
CALL_GROFF = $(GROFF) -T$(subst $*.,,$@) -mman $< > $@

%.html %.ascii: %.doc
        $(CALL_GROFF)

.DEFAULT: all
all: $(DOC_FILES)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm $(DOC_FILES)
```

But it doesn't work, because `make` believes that *all* files are created with one command (much like `&` in modern make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html)

Obviously I can do

```
GROFF := groff
DOCS := man README

DOC_FILES = $(foreach doc,$(DOCS),$(doc).html $(doc).ascii)
CALL_GROFF = $(GROFF) -T$(subst $*.,,$@) -mman $< > $@

%.ascii: %.doc
        $(CALL_GROFF)

%.html: %.doc
        $(CALL_GROFF)

.DEFAULT: all
all: $(DOC_FILES)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm $(DOC_FILES)
```

But it is a kind of copy-paste.

Could it be solved with GNU make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how this works; it's a long-standing feature. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

> Pattern rules may have more than one target; however, every target must contain a % character. Pattern rules are always treated as grouped targets (see [Multiple Targets in a Rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets)) regardless of whether they use the : or &: separator.

As example states, it was meant to deal with programs that generate more than one output in one invocation, like `bison`. You can either update your recipe to generate both files in one shot, or keep the rules separated as you do now.